# Excel VBA: How can I make the offset in this code to go over hidden columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

**This is the code for which I need to make the offset take place only for visible cells:**

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing And (Range("A1") = "12345") Then
        Range("F3").Offset(0, 1) = Range("F3").Offset(0, 1).Value + Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I am a noob in VBA and I really don't know how to make that offset work. It would fix all my problems if somebody can give me a solution.

The code should work like this:

**If A1 = 12345, show the sum of B1 in G3 (Offset by 1 of F3).**

**But if the G3 is hidden, show the result in H3, and if G3 and H3 are hidden, show the result in I3 and so on.**

Do you have any idea how to accomplish this ?
I am open to use a formula in the spreadsheet to get the same result but I don't know how to make that one also.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result. Judging by the comments below, this may well be an XY problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing And (Range("A1") = "12345") Then
        For i = 6 To Columns.Count
            If Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
                Range("F3").Offset(0, i - 6) = Range("F3").Offset(0, i - 6).Value + Target.Value
                GoTo MyEnd
            End If
        Next i
    End If
MyEnd:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Justin for your answer. It works perfectly. I have another question for you and if you can help me,  it would be extraordinary.  It is about the same thing. Here is the link:  https://superuser.com/questions/1657067/excel-vba-how-can-i-multiply-this-code-10-times-for-10-different-h13-b13-cells